# Android - getByName() does not resolve hostname / How to resolve hostnames to IPs in Android Network?

Tags: android, networking, ip, hostname, android-networking

I'm writing an application which can find hosts in the local network by hostnames. In c++ WIN32 I use getaddrinfo() from Ws2tcpip.h and it is always working on each network I've tried it. In android java I use getByName() from java.Net.InetAddress to get the IP of the host by its hostname. This android implementation does not work in each network. Especially in my office-network with my own machine named "PC01" it does not work. It does not return the IP address, it throws an UnknownHostException if I enter "PC01".

So I've tried something: I debugged my c++ WIN32 application from another machine than PC01 and let my machine PC01 send packets to the machine on which I was debugging the code so I could look up the hostname manually by checking the attributes of the incoming packets. As excepted it was "PC01". While I did exactly the same with my android java application, the methods getHostname() and getCanonicalHostname() returned both the string represantation of the IP of PC01 instead of a string of its hostname. So now it was clear why getByName() could not find my machine, as it was resolved as "IP of PC01" and not "PC01". 
After some research I found out that there might be a problem with the Naming Service which Java/Android is using. Since c++ is using WINS, which seems to work fine for me, the naming service of the java app do not resolve the hostname properly (I've also got other examples of this behaviour, so my machine/network is not the only one!).

My First Question: Is there a java android alternative to getHostName() or an alternative to another Naming Service in order to resolve the hostname properly in each network?

My NDK workaround: As I already explained, I think that the resolving does fail in the java api, so I wanted to make a NDK workaround using the gethostbyname() function from c / netdb.h. So I wrote a sample app to see whether it will work or not. Here is my code:

Simple MyActivity which passes a hardcoded string of the hostname to the native function:

```
package david.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Example of a call to a native method
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        String hostname = "PC01";
    tv.setText(stringFromJNI(hostname));
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI(String hostname);

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
}
```

and the native function code which converts the jstring to std:string, does the gethostbynme() operation and returns the result into jstring:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_david_test_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */, jstring hostname) {

        //convert to std::string
        const jsize len = env->GetStringUTFLength(hostname);
        const char* strChars = env->GetStringUTFChars(hostname, (jboolean *)0);

        std::string hostnameStr(strChars, (unsigned long) len);

        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(hostname, strChars);
        //end convert


        struct hostent* result;

        result = gethostbyname(hostnameStr.c_str());

        char* ip = result->h_addr_list[0];

        return env->NewStringUTF(ip);
}
```

The thing that is not working on this code is that 'result' is always NULL. So My Second Question: Did I something wrong by writing the NDK-code or does my plan not work (so the native code in java also uses the same Name Service just like the normal java code)?

**EDIT 2017-09-08:**

Solved my NDK implementation problem, but I have still the same 'weird' behaviour though. The scenario: With the following code I want to check by native methods whether the hostname of my machine gets resolved properly. For this I am using the functions [getaddrinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx) and [getnameinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms738532(v=vs.85).aspx) (which are working correctly on each device when written in c/c++/uwp/win32). So what I want to do with this code is first to see what result I get by resolving the hostname by ip and then vice cersa. The main activity in java-code stays the same as above, only the native part is changed:

Let the given hostname be my machine's hostname (PC01) and let the given harcoded IP be the ip of my machine (IP_MACHINE). NOTE: All permissions for internet are granted in the appmanifest.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_david_test_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */, jstring hostname) {

        //convert to std::string
        const jsize len = env->GetStringUTFLength(hostname);
        const char* strChars = env->GetStringUTFChars(hostname, (jboolean *)0);

        // hostnameStr == hostname of my machine
        std::string hostnameStr(strChars, (unsigned long) len);

        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(hostname, strChars);
        //end convert

        // get ip by hostname:
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
        int rv;

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = 6;
        hints.ai_flags = 2;


        rv = getaddrinfo(hostnameStr.c_str(), NULL, &hints, &servinfo);
        // rv == 7
        char* error = (char*)gai_strerror(rv);
        // error == "No address asociated with hostname"

    // get hostname by ip:
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, IP_MACHINE, &sa.sin_addr);

    char node[NI_MAXHOST];
    int res = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa), node, sizeof(node), NULL, NULL, NI_NOFQDN);
    // res == 0
    char* error2 = (char*) gai_strerror(res);
    // error2 == "Success"

    return env->NewStringUTF(node);
    // node == "PC01.domain.local"
}
```

*Conclusion:*

1. getnameinfo works. But it does not work correctly, as the `NI_NOFQDN` flag says that the hostname returned should be without the specific domain, but it get returned with it (domain.local).
2. getaddrinfo does not work at all. I tried PC01 and PC01.domain.local, as the getnameinfo function returns it with the domain addition - so it is even more weird that the getnameinfo function can resolve the hostname and the getaddrinfo function cannot do it.
3. Seems like my plan is not working and the reason that hinder the proper hostnameresolution in android does also exist if using native code.

With this new conclusions and the new test, could you think of a reason why it is not working on android/java and furhtermore how I can fix it or how I can work around it? Being honest, this is a actually quite simple thing to do, why it does not work as wanted.

**EDIT 2017-09-15:**

In order to proof my opinion that this is a problem of java, I wrote a simple testclass testing the getByName()-function from java in `Eclipse using jdk`. *It worked properly in my network with the hostname which does not get resolved by the android getByName!* So now I can say that this a android-problem. Here is the code I used:

```
package testpackage;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InetAddress ia;
        try{
        ia = InetAddress.getByName("PC01");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            ia = null;
        }
        if(ia != null){
                System.out.println(ia.getHostAddress().toString()); 
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("nope!");    
        }

    }

}
```

Result:

```
IP of PC01
```

**EDIT 2018-04-17:**

I've still not found any solution for my problem so far. As I see there are apps in the Google Play Store which are successfully doing this - so there must be a solution for my problem.

My current thoughts: I want to emulate the steps which a windows client is doing to resolve the hostname to an IP (like WINS). How can I do this (on low level socket programming maybe)?

Comment: I am afraid it's not about Java vs c++, but rather the Windows network, see https://serverfault.com/q/116716/391162

Comment: @AlexCohn I'm sorry, I just don't understand it, can you explain what information I can get from your post and how it helps me?